# GAS - Prevent button click event from opening new browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have some Google Sheets app script code that hits an API and updates a field in a sidebar based on some user input. Everything works as expected with the exception of the button used to trigger the API call from the sidebar. For some reason, clicking the button opens a new, blank tab in the browser.

My best guess is that I'm somehow implementing the `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()` incorrectly but I've been unable to confirm this. Any help would be much appreciated.

## Sidebar.html

This is the full sidebar file that I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#narrative-from-selection').click(getNarrative);
      });
      function getNarrative(narrative) {
        //document.getElementById('narrative-response').innerHTML = narrative.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');
        var projectName = $('#project-name').val();
        var templateName = $('#template-name').val();
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(
            function(narrative) {
              $('#narrative-response').html(narrative);
            })
          .withUserObject(this)
          .generateContentForSelected(projectName, templateName);
      }
    </script>
  <body>
    <div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form>
      Project Name: <input type="text" name="project-name" id="project-name" onchange="google.script.run.updateProjectAndTemplateNames(this.parentNode)"><br />
      Template Name: <input type="text" name="template-name" id="template-name" onchange="google.script.run.updateProjectAndTemplateNames(this.parentNode)"><br />
      <button id="narrative-from-selection">Generate from Selection</button><br /><br />
      Response:<br /><br />
      <div id="narrative-response"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Code.gs

Here is the overview of the relevant function that I'm using (the info used to hit the API is removed but I've tested that piece many times and it returns exactly what I expect it to send back).

```
function generateContentForSelected(projectName, templateName) {
  // go do some API magic here
  var narrative = "This is a test string.";
  return narrative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through a ton of trial and error, I figured out what was causing the issue, though I'm still unsure why it's causing the new tab to open. Apparently, something about the way app script makes an asynchronous call using a form is a little quirky. I stripped the `<form>` and `</form>` tags out of the Sidebar.html file and everything works as expected.

If there's a better method to correct this, or if I've gone about this all wrong from the start, I'd be interested to know how to structure this more effectively. But, I did get it working at least.